# CSS navigation menu with rollover and selected effects. How do I apply the "selected"?

Tags: html, css

I don't know HTML or much coding. Below is a copy and paste, something I didn't create. Basically we have a single image containing three different menu sections (home, blog, contact) and the four different states that the menu could be in: normal, hover, clicked and active.

The selected/active, is only working on the home page. How do I make the active image stick to the other images associated with the other pages?

**P.S. I don't know anything about anything, so it would be most helpful if you can give me a step by step on what the exact code should be used (given the exact coding below) and where to place it.**

CSS Codes:

```
#ul.cssmenu a { background:url(header-icon-strip.png); }
  .ul.cssmenu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    }



.displace {
    position: absolute;
    left: -5000px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li {
    float: left;
    }

ul.cssmenu li a {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url('http://www.webvamp.co.uk/uploads//2009/03/sprite.gif');
    }

/*
*   Normal Links
*/
ul.cssmenu li.home a {
    background-position: 0 0;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.blog a {
    background-position: -150px 0;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.contact a {
    background-position: -300px 0;
    }

/*
*   Hover Links
*/
ul.cssmenu li.home a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -44px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.blog a:hover {
    background-position: -150px -44px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.contact a:hover {
    background-position: -300px -44px;
    }

/*
*   Clicked Links
*/
ul.cssmenu li.home a:active {
    background-position: 0 -88px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.blog a:active {
    background-position: -150px -88px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.contact a:active {
    background-position: -300px -88px;
    }

/*

*   Selected/Active Links
*/
ul.cssmenu li.home a.selected {
    background-position: 0 -132px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.blog a.selected {
    background-position: -150px -132px;
    }

ul.cssmenu li.contact a.selected {
    background-position: -300px -132px;
    }
```

Div menu code:

```
<ul class="cssmenu">

<li class="home"><a href="http://example.com/" class="selected" title="Home"><span class="displace">Home</span></a></li>

<li class="blog"><a href="http://example.com/blog.html/"  title="Blog"><span class="displace">Blog</span></a></li>

<li class="contact"><a href="http://example.com/contact.html/" title="Contact"><span class="displace">Contact</span></a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with individual HTML pages, you should edit each one to make the respective menu item to have the selected/active class.

**home.html**

```
<ul class="cssmenu">
  <li class="home"><a href="http://example.com/" class="selected" title="Home"><span class="displace">Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="blog"><a href="http://example.com/blog.html/"  title="Blog"><span class="displace">Blog</span></a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="http://example.com/contact.html/" title="Contact"><span class="displace">Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**blog.html**

```
<ul class="cssmenu">
  <li class="home"><a href="http://example.com/" title="Home"><span class="displace">Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="blog"><a href="http://example.com/blog.html/" class="selected" title="Blog"><span class="displace">Blog</span></a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="http://example.com/contact.html/" title="Contact"><span class="displace">Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

and so on...

Comment: Thank you Kumiau, I am working with this under www.blogger.com

So I am not sure if it actually individual pages. I tired the code and it created another menu below the first one, only this time, the blog was stuck on selected, no matter what page. Just like the first menu, the home page is stuck on active, no matter what actual page was active. :(

Comment: I haven't worked with blogger, found this guide that may help you. http://www.bloggersentral.com/2010/02/highlighting-current-page-tab-in.html

Comment: Thanks Kumiau, i was under the impression that blogger is setup to accept any coding variables and it's been true so far. I mean the sprite image css works and all other modifications I ever tried, just this "selected" bit is giving me trouble.

I guess I will goto the blogger help fourms and see what i can find out there. 

Thanks again for all your help. The link you gave doesn't work with this the sprite css coding I already have and I cant find a blogger tutorial about sprite navigation. But thank you for your efforts!